# Making a WordPress Gutenberg Field "required"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

How do we make a WordPress Gutenberg attribute a required attribute? Curious if a property or attribute parameter can be defined, either in block.json or Edit.js, to avoid writing custom logic for each attribute.

block.json:

```
"attributes": {
    "blockSubTitle": {
        "type": "string",
        "default": "OVERVIEW"
    },
    "blockImage": {
        "type": "string",
        "default": null
    },
    "blockImageId": {
        "type": "integer",
        "default": null
    },
    "topPadding": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "default": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block attributes can be updated in the Edit() function by using WordPress Gutenberg controls like a [TextControl](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/text-control/) for a `string` or [NumberControl](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/number-control/) for `integer` and [ToggleControl](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/toggle-control/) for `boolean` values.

All of these controls render out standard HTML form inputs which accept the `required` attribute. By adding your own CSS `className`, you can gain greater styling control over the required inputs for user feedback.

Eg. TextControl

```jsx
<TextControl
    label="Sub Title"
    help="Required"
    ...
    className="is-required" // or your own class name
    required // this makes the input required 
/>
```

As there is no default style for `*:required:invalid` in the Editor stylesheet, by adding your own error styles in `editor.scss`, the User will know when the input is required or in error:

**editor.scss**

```scss
/* Add a red asterisk after label to indicate required field */
.is-required * label::after{
    color:#cc1818;
    content:" *" 
}

*:required:invalid {
    border-color:#cc1818;
    
    &:focus{
        border-color:#cc1818;
        box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #cc1818;
    }
}
```

Depending on the purpose of the required block attributes, indicating the field is required and providing a safe default value in `block.json` may be enough. However, if the required attribute is critical (eg. could potentially break something), then [dispatching error notices](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-notices/#createerrornotice) for invalid values and [preventing the post content from saving](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor/#lockpostsaving) is the next step. Below is a complete example for a TextControl:

**edit.js**

```js
import { InspectorControls, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { PanelBody, TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { store as noticesStore } from '@wordpress/notices';

import './editor.scss';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const { blockSubTitle } = attributes;

    const { createErrorNotice, removeNotice } = useDispatch(noticesStore);

    const setSubTitle = (value) => {

        /* String cannot be empty */
        if (value.length == 0) {

            /* Dispatch error notice */
            createErrorNotice('Sub title is required', {
                id: 'subtitle-required',
                isDismissible: false,
            });

            /* Prevent post content from saving and autosaving */
            wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').lockPostSaving('subtitle-required');
            wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').lockPostAutosaving('subtitle-required');

        } else {
            /* Save valid value */
            setAttributes({ blockSubTitle: value });

            /* Remove notice */
            removeNotice('subtitle-required');

            /* Unlock post */
            wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').unlockPostSaving('subtitle-required');
            wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').unlockPostAutosaving('subtitle-required');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody>
                    <TextControl
                        label="Sub Title"
                        help="Required"
                        value={blockSubTitle}
                        onChange={(value) => setSubTitle(value)}
                        className="is-required"
                        required
                    />
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
            <h2>{blockSubTitle}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The example `edit.js` combined with `editor.scss` when no value is given, renders:
[image: Input Error]